# Can't convert Ubuntu distro from WSL1 to WSL2

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have installed Ubunu (Version: 22.04) on my Windows 10 (Version: 21H2, Build: 19044) but it's not converting to WSL2 after meeting all the requirements. I have already installed the latest linux karnel update and enabled appropriate windows features (Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Subsystem for Linux). Virtualization is also enabled in my BIOS setting but it's still not converting to WSL2.

According to some suggestions I have uninstalled my VirtualBox application and enabled Hyper-V, Windows Hypervisor Platform features but none of these resolved the issue.

If i run this command in PowerShell -

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
```

I get this error -

```
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For information please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2-install
```

While I have already enabled these features. Can anyone tell me how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: It does not appear that Virtual Machine Platform installed on your system.

Comment: Try to install the Hyper-V feature, which implicitly includes Virtual Machine Platform.

Comment: @Ramhound I have enabled this feature from control panel and VTx is also enabled in BIOS but the error message continuously telling me to enable this two features while i have done it already. Do you think there are other factors which are preventing it from conversion?

Comment: @harrymc I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: Try to uninstall WSL and Virtual Machine Platform and Hyper-V, reboot and reinstall and reboot again.

Comment: @MohammadSiam - VMP isn’t enabled from the Control Panel

Comment: I agree uninstall every optional feature you installed, reboot, then run **wsl --install** in an elevated prompt. Before you do this, verify Windows is fully updated, in order to guarantee compatibility with the Windows Store version of WSL. Windows Store version of WSL is the only version being fully supported at this time.

Comment: @Ramhound It worked! I reinstalled every optional feature and also uninstalled my Ubuntu distro (which I think wasn't necessary but I did) then ran this command `wsl --install -d Ubuntu`. Hopefully, it installed the Ubuntu distro again but in WSL2. Thank you so much for helping me out.